# AWS SNS filter policy doesn't support Exists operator for array fields?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have SNS topic and SQS queue. I'd like to send some messages from SNS to SQS. I have SNS filter policy that uses `exists` operator

```
ResultTopicToAlertSqs:
  Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
  Properties:
    TopicArn: !Ref ResultTopic
    Endpoint: !GetAtt AlertsQueue.Arn
    Protocol: "sqs"
    RawMessageDelivery: true
    FilterPolicyScope: MessageBody
    FilterPolicy: '{ "some-id": [{"exists": true}] }'
```

Everything works fine for messages where exists is used with general fields, but doesn't work with fields that are array. I have `results` array field, using `'{ "results": [{"exists": true}] }'` filter gives me empty SQS queue when messages with `results: [ *something* ]` are sent to SNS.

What am I doing wrong?